# Remap key to a UTF character from another keyboard layout in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode

I'm using KeyMapper to remap some of the keys on my keyboard, but I haven't figured out how to do this specific thing.

I need a couple of Unicode characters from a different keyboard layout, so I can't just remap a key to another key or shortcut. Maybe I can use some complex key combination like in Windows where you use Alt+keypad to call UTF characters?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be different between different distributions, and, typically there may also difference between working in a terminal or with graphical programs.

I use 'key composing' to make unicode characters. This means that one key on the keyboard is assigned the 'compose' character. I can now type, eg. 'Compose', then '1' then '2', and get '½'. This works great for me. There's a large table already defined. To enable it, I defined

```
keycode 134 = Multi_key
```

in the file .Xmodmap in my home directory. Look for 'linux compose key' in google for more info. Never needed it, but I'm quite sure you can edit the compose table to add/modify other combinations.

In that same file (.Xmodmap) you can directly assign characters to keys too.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use your method, but after learning about the compose key I added a macro in KeyMapper and mapped it to the key I needed.